# ASP.NET MVC display image from json result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Image is not displaying from json result value. Below is my Controller Action and Jquery

```
$.post('/User/Comment/',{commentId=Id},function(data){

  $("#cbox").append("<img src="'+data.ImagePath+'" />")
```

});

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Comment(string commentId){
     var data=(from p in db.commentdb
     join q in db.profileImage
     on p.Email equals q.Email
     where p.commentId==commentId
     select new
    {
     Name=p.Fullname,
     Comment=p.Comment
     ImagePath=q.ImagePath
     });
    return Json(data,jsonrequestbehavior.allowget)
   }
```

Please help to fix this. Just I need to display image on razor view based on json return image path

Comment: Looks like you're mixing single quotes with double. Try "<img src=\""+data.ImagePath+"\" />" instead

Comment: have you tried fixing your append to: `$("#cbox").append("<img src='" + data.ImagePath + "' />")` ?

Comment: Thanks,I will try and will update outcome

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("#cbox").append("<img src="'+data.ImagePath+'" />")
```

to

```
 $("#cbox").append("<img src='" +data.ImagePath+ "' />")
```